# Group by column in pandas dataframe and average arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, mean

I have a movie dataframe with movie names, their respective genre, and vector representation (numpy arrays).

```
ID  Year    Title   Genre   Word Vector
1   2003.0  Dinosaur Planet Documentary [-0.55423898, -0.72544044, 0.33189204, -0.1720...
2   2004.0  Isle of Man TT 2004 Review  Sports & Fitness    [-0.373265237, -1.07549703, -0.469254494, -0.4...
3   1997.0  Character   Foreign [-1.57682264, -0.91265768, 2.43038678, -0.2114...
4   1994.0  Paula Abdul's Get Up & Dance    Sports & Fitness    [0.3096168, -0.57186663, 0.39008939, 0.2868615...
5   2004.0  The Rise and Fall of ECW    Sports & Fitness    [0.17175879, -2.38005066, -0.45771399, 1.32608...
```

I'd like to group by genre and get each genre's average vector representation (the component wise average of each movie vector in the genre).

---

I first tried:

```
movie_df.groupby(['Genre']).mean()
```

But the built in mean function isn't able to take the mean of numpy arrays.

I tried creating my own function to do so and then apply it to each group, but I'm not sure this is using apply correctly:

```
def vector_average(group):
   series_to_array = np.array(group.tolist())
   return np.mean(series_to_array, axis = 0)

movie_df.groupby(['Genre']).apply(vector_average)
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please print out `df.head(5)` and paste it here?

Comment: Yes, but in the question.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the best way to provide a sample of the dataframe - advice here would be appreciated too!

Comment: Okay. Your `Word Vector` is a column of numpy arrays or lists?

Comment: they're numpy arrays

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly, to get the component-wise averages you can simply apply `np.mean` to the `'Word Vector'` SeriesGroupBy explicitly.

```
df.groupby('Genre')['Word Vector'].apply(np.mean)
```

---

**Demo**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': list('ABCDEFGHIJ'), 
                       'Genre': list('ABCBBDCDED'), 
                       'Word Vector': [np.random.randint(0, 10, 10) 
                                       for _ in range(len('ABCDEFGHIJ'))]})

>>> df

  Genre Title                     Word Vector
0     A     A  [3, 6, 8, 0, 4, 8, 1, 4, 0, 1]
1     B     B  [5, 4, 4, 4, 8, 7, 4, 3, 7, 2]
2     C     C  [1, 7, 6, 7, 3, 3, 8, 1, 8, 1]
3     B     D  [0, 4, 6, 7, 1, 5, 5, 0, 6, 7]
4     B     E  [8, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 4, 9, 1]
5     D     F  [7, 9, 7, 8, 8, 7, 2, 9, 1, 3]
6     C     G  [0, 7, 1, 9, 6, 2, 1, 0, 3, 7]
7     D     H  [4, 7, 9, 4, 1, 5, 0, 3, 0, 6]
8     E     I  [5, 1, 5, 1, 8, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]
9     D     J  [7, 9, 0, 1, 8, 3, 8, 8, 1, 0]

>>> df.groupby('Genre')['Word Vector'].apply(np.mean)

Genre
A    [3.0, 6.0, 8.0, 0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 1.0, 4.0, 0.0, ...
B    [4.33333333333, 3.33333333333, 3.66666666667, ...
C    [0.5, 7.0, 3.5, 8.0, 4.5, 2.5, 4.5, 0.5, 5.5, ...
D    [6.0, 8.33333333333, 5.33333333333, 4.33333333...
E    [5.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0, 8.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 5.0, ...
Name: Word Vector, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you this works!  For the sake of completeness I had tried movie_df.groupby(['Genre']).apply(np.mean).  It had outputs for the ID & Year column but nothing for the vector column?

Comment: @perennial_nomad If you try and call `np.mean` on the entire DataFrame, it will only provide results for columns with numeric datatypes - here, `'Word Vector'` is of type object. And you're welcome!

Comment: Another followup - this returns a pandas series and when I try to write this to a dataframe using to_frame, it only returns the Word Vector column with the genres as labels on the side.  Is there a way to directly convert into a 20 x 2 df with 'Genre' and 'Word Vectors'?

Comment: @perennial_nomad Call `.reset_index()` on the solution I provided above, maybe :)

Answer (score 0):

FYI

If you have lists of numbers in your column "Word Vector", you must cast it in numpy arrays before :

```
df['Word Vector'] = df['Word Vector'].apply(np.array)
df.groupby('Genre')['Word Vector'].apply(np.mean)#.apply(list)
```