# Unprecedented TypeError using groupby and mean of vectors in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

This is a sample data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cat' : ['a', 'a', 'b'], 'Vec' : [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]})

print (df)
  Cat        Vec
0   a  [1, 2, 3]
1   a  [4, 5, 6]
2   b  [1, 2, 3]
```

My goal is to groupby `Cat` and take the mean of these vectors along the 0th axis:

```
                 Vec
Cat                 
a    [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
b    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

The first and obvious solution seemed to be:

```
df.groupby('Cat').Vec.apply(np.mean)
```

But this gives me:

```
TypeError: Could not convert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] to numeric
```

However, this works:

```
df.groupby('Cat').Vec.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.tolist(), axis=0))
```

Also, this same technique works to good effect in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45726608/4909087

It seems a bit roundabout. Why does the error occur with the first method and how do I fix that?

Comment: This is interesting. Looks like we need either an ndarray or simple values to apply `np.mean` like this, see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6fe68325de93a5f745ff49eac57589d33a1d53c1/pandas/core/nanops.py#L770) in the source code. Not so sure what a solution is atm though.

Comment: @Mitch Funny you should respond to this. This question is inspired from the last answer you wrote. I tried something much like your answer but got this error, so was looking for an alternative solution. But when I saw you post this solution to good effect, I was flummoxed.

Comment: Haha yeah, I figured! Playing around with it now.

Comment: @CoryMadden I've included a sample output below input.

Comment: Fundamentally, `numpy` and by extension `pandas` is not really designed for working with arrays of lists in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cat': ['a', 'a', 'b'],
    'Vec': [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]
})


df.groupby('Cat').Vec.apply(np.mean)

Cat
a    [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
b    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
Name: Vec, dtype: object
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cat': ['a', 'a', 'b'],
    'Vec': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
})

df.Vec.apply(np.array).groupby(df.Cat).apply(np.mean)

Cat
a    [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
b    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
Name: Vec, dtype: object
```

---

The issue is that `np.mean` can take a list of lists, but not an array of lists.

See these examples

```
np.mean(df.loc[df.Cat.eq('a'), 'Vec'].values, 0)
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-380-279352aca85f> in <module>()
> ----> 1 np.mean(df.loc[df.Cat.eq('a'), 'Vec'].values, 0)
>
> //anaconda/envs/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
>    2907 
>    2908     return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
> -> 2909                           out=out, **kwargs)
>    2910 
>    2911 
>
> //anaconda/envs/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
>      80             ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
>      81     else:
> ---> 82         ret = ret / rcount
>      83 
>      84     return ret
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
> ```

---

```
np.mean(df.loc[df.Cat.eq('a'), 'Vec'].values.tolist(), 0)

array([ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5])
```

Comment: This is interesting. Why does it not work unless the type is `np.array`  to begin with?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ See the source code line I linked above - there is handling for ndarrays, but not for a Python list.

Comment: @Mitch I suspect that if the check was not made, passing lists should work because numpy can handle them. What do you say?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes indeed, still trying to assert _why_ exactly we enter that check :)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Ah, so by default, an array of lists is passed. Okay... this makes sense! Thanks again.